# How to handle htmlentities() exception in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

Everyone. I'm facing with below error

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: E:\accounting\resources\views\index.blade.php)
```

when in run this query in laravel and don't know what I'm missing, any help.
thanks
The query:

```
 $purchase = DB::table('purchases')
        ->join('currencies', 'currencies.cur_id', '=', 'purchases.currency_id')
        ->selectRaw('purchases.*, currencies.currency ,SUM(purchases.quantity*unit_price) as total, SUM(purchases.c_price*quantity) as usd_total')
        ->first();
```

View:

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
  <p class="text-elg text-strong mb-0">
  {{ number_format($purchase->usd_total,2) }}
                                        </p>
        <span>Purchases</span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the **$purchase** variable has data or not before printing the **$purchase->usd_total**

in your view page you can check something like below

```
@if(count($purchase)>0)

{{ number_format($purchase->usd_total,2) }}

@endif
```

of course you can use **php if** too.I have used **blade if**

hope this will help. :) :) :)